# Problems comparing strings (BASH)

Tags: linux, string, bash, if-statement, string-comparison

I'm trying to compare 2 strings. One comes from a file through the grep command and the other one never changes because I'm always comparing it with the ones I create while reading file texts. If they are equal, the program should print the data associated with the content that the new string contains. I've tried with all the syntax that bash allows (cause I'm new at bash) but it is just not working like I expected. It looks like the second `if` doesn't work, because I tried earlier without that and only print the strings (`echo $text`) and it worked, but not the proper way as the exercise I'm doing asks for. I have to show in the console only the pid and state of the processes that are running.

```
cd
cd /proc
run="State: S (sleeping)"
for i in $( ls -d */); 
do
    cd $i
    if [ -f /proc/$i/status ];
        then    text="`grep -w "S" status`"
             if [ "$text" == "$run" ]
                then grep -w "Pid" status
                     grep -w "State" status
             fi
             cd /proc
        else cd /proc
    fi
done
;;
```

Comment: It is often simpler to run a (portion of a) script that does `cd somewhere` and then does another `cd back.to.where.it.started` as a sub-shell which simply changes to the target directory and exits.  The initial `cd` to `$HOME` is a little pointless too.  It's funny to check for `/proc/$i/status` and then read `./status`, though it is actually the same file.  Also, processing the output from `ls` is a fraught process — beware in general, though it is probably reasonably safe in this example.

Answer (score 0):

Your `run` variable contains `State:<space>S (sleeping)`, but `/proc/<pid>/status` files contain `State:<tab>S (sleeping)` (at least, on my system). So you should replace that space character with tab character.